# Stationarity & seasonality in R

Tags: r, stationarity, seasonality

I have a weekly number of items sold from 2012 to 2014. 2014 not being complete. So bassically two periods. I am looking at seasonality and stationarity of the response variable (# of items sold)

I have first plotted them against time

![response in time][1]

I then had did stl decomposition in suspicion of trend and seasonality

![stl decomposition][2]

However my data is stationary without any transformation

![enter image description here][3]
![enter image description here][4]

All my testing attests to stationarity of course...
so I did

```
boxplot(Dealer_Traffic~month, data=total, xlab= "Month", ylab = "Traffic to Dealer")
```

to see differences in mean of sales through month. Month was created using dates I had to create the month a given observation belonged to.

![Boxplot][5]

and difference in mean observed are not significant. WHAT????

![ANOVA][6]

and here is the acf and pacf

![acf and pacf][7]

So could I conclude that my raw data is stationary hence needs no transformation?

Can I conclude that an ARIMA would be suitable? Which ARIMA model would you recommend?

It seems like I cannot have photos here. So basically all my tests reject nonstationarity but I observe seasonality and trend in stl decomposition. No difference between monthly means. I tried 
 pp test Box.test kpss and adf.test for first and pairwise.t.test and aov for means tuckey.

Can I conclude that the series is stationary?

Comment: Is this a specific programming question, or do you really need statistical advice. If the latter, you probably should be posting to [stats.se] instead. We're not here to tell you how to analyze your data. For that you need a statistician, not a programmer.

Comment: Oh then my bad I will post on cross validated. I know the programming I need statistician falir.